# When I read excel file to python, time format has changed

Tags: python, excel, pandas

when I read the excel file to python.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('copy.xlsx')
data
```

Some part of my time data was uploaded successfully but another part of the time data has some problems. Problem is on these columns (in_time, call_time, process_in_time, out_time).

Why is this happening?
And how to handle and normalize this time data?
The Excel data link is here >[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nW0y-SkNDXpMewLyxUb5Icj18EOIXmfV6rhzH24vpr8/edit#gid=121237145)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71X1C.png)

Comment: Please post your code where you read in the data.

Comment: <import pandas as pd>
<data = pd.read_excel('copy.xlsx')>
<data>

Comment: In Excel, each and every cell can have its own type and format. But to load a sheet in Pandas with not too much trouble, 1/ the type and format should be consistent per column, and 2/ **you** should know what that type and format is. If any of those 2 assumptions are wrong, you are likely to obtain unexpected result... Unfortunately, an image contains no information on the actual cell types.

Comment: @SergeBallesta When I read the excel file to python, I change the type of the columns to "time" format in excel and then read it to python

Comment: You should try to isolate the problematic cells. If you can show what Excel shows and what pandas gets on a small set of data, maybe we can try to understand what happens. Here you only says *data has some problems* which contains little if any information. We need at least input data, and expected and actual data. Ideally the sample should contain at least one cell that is correctly processed and one that is not.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I downloaded sample data (google sheets) to the post

Comment: I asked you to describe the **expected** and **actual** results. Currently, you uploaded a Google Sheet that can be downloaded to an Excel file and then loaded in Pandas. But I still have no ideas of what the *some problems* can be... You should read again what a [mre] is supposed to be.